# Google Deployment Manager Extensions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I'm curious if anybody had any success integration Google API libraries into DM so that holes in deployment manager's offerings can be covered by the user themselves.

https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/import-python-libraries

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Action" feature in DM for any GCP apis. 
see code example from google's example repo.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/523b87967eab7e1aa37744ac35042c62950eba30/examples/v2/bigtable/python/bigtable.py

It can be used for third party APIs as well

https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/type-providers/creating-type-provider

Answer (score 0):

Deployment Manager will not allow any library to do network communication, which means no Google API library will work.

For REST APIs the type-provider is the best solution:

https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/type-providers/creating-type-provider

Actions have limited usability because they are asynchronous and you cannot process the return state of the call.